# How can I jump factor-data in a correlation function?

Tags: r, correlation

I'm an absolute beginner and I want to calculate correlations in my data set.

A couple of columns are factor data, so I want to jump those columns, as apparently it is not possible to calculate correlations for them. How can I do this?

I tried adding something like `use = is.factor==FALSE`. but that is apparently not possible :-)

Code in R:

```r
cor(my_data_frame, use = "complete.obs")
```

> Error in cor(my_data_frame, use = "complete.obs") : 'x' muss numerisch sein
>   (in english: 'x' has to be numerical)

Comment: use `Filter(is.numeric, my_data_frame)` as the dataset to only include numeric data

Comment: `cor(sapply(OrchardSprays, rank))` will take the ranks within each column and then calculate the correlation matrix of the ranks.  That way you don't have to skip the factor columns.  Also to visually look at pairs try `pairs(OrchardSprays)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude them from your dataset and run the correlation on the remaining:

```
data=yourData[ , -which(names(YourData) %in% c("thefirst factor","2nd factor","third"))])
```

Comment: there are 80 columns in total, ca. 40 are factor columns, they have up to 10 levels each... so this solution is a lot of work...

Comment: Don't expect a miracle. this might make it easier:
use this to get column indexes:
as.data.frame(colnames(data))
then use index numbers:
data[,-c(1,3,other numbers you don't want)]